# Xamarin Forms - Prism bound properties - Rendering issue

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, prism

Git: https://github.com/jimmyt1988/Test

---

I'm running on desktop windows 10 pc on UWP Local device "emulator"

---

I have a deep integer property in my view model that gets incremented by a button command.

When i do, the number disapears from the screen, and then if i resize my application, it will render correctly again.

What's happening?

It seems to work on the Android emulator.

[image]

**Code**

```
public DelegateCommand<FoodGroupModel> SubtractFromAmountEatenCommand { get; private set; }

...

SubtractFromAmountEatenCommand = new DelegateCommand<FoodGroupModel>((foodGroup) => SubtractFromAmountEaten(foodGroup));

...

public void SubtractFromAmountEaten(FoodGroupModel foodGroup)
{
    if(foodGroup.AmountEaten != 0)
    {
        foodGroup.AmountEaten--;
    }
}

...

public class FoodGroupModel : BindableBase
{
    private int _amountEaten;
    public int AmountEaten
    {
        get { return _amountEaten; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _amountEaten, value); }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="...Views.MealPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding Meal.Number}"/>
        <ListView x:Name="FoodGroupsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Meal.FoodGroups}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" TextColor="#bababa" Text="Group"></Label>
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" />

                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" TextColor="#bababa" Text="Qty"></Label>
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding AmountEaten}" />

                                <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4"
                                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference FoodGroupsListView}, Path=BindingContext.UndoAmountEatenByOneCommand}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                        Text="✖"></Button>

                                <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5"
                                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference FoodGroupsListView}, Path=BindingContext.SubtractFromAmountEatenCommand}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                        Text="✔"></Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Any way i can make this question better?

Comment: Anyway I'm still trying to reproduce. Upload a reproduce project to github or somewhere may be better.

Comment: @Sunteen-MSFT - I've added the github repo - https://github.com/jimmyt1988/Test/tree/master/DailyPlate/DailyPlate

Comment: @Sunteen-MSFT - I corrected navigation so if you run it it will work and you can get to the faulty page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When i do, the number disapears from the screen, and then if i resize my application, it will render correctly again.

You might run into an issue: The changed notification of property binding won't work well(May be related to rerender) inside Xamarin `ListView`, Please report it in here: [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/newbug)

In Windows runtime platform(Win/WP 8.1 & UWP), we have to use a workaround to temporarily avoid this:

```
private void RefreashFoodGroupModel()
        {
            if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Windows || Device.OS == TargetPlatform.WinPhone)
            {
                //var index = Meal.FoodGroups.IndexOf(foodGroup);
                //Meal.FoodGroups.RemoveAt(index);
                //Meal.FoodGroups.Insert(index, foodGroup);

                var t = Meal.FoodGroups;
                Meal.FoodGroups = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<FoodGroupModel>();
                foreach (var item in t)
                {
                    Meal.FoodGroups.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
```

Call the above method to refresh data after data change:

```
public void SubtractFromAmountEaten(FoodGroupModel foodGroup)
        {
            if(foodGroup.AmountEaten != 0)
            {
                foodGroup.AmountEaten--;
                RefreashFoodGroupModel();
            }
        }

        public void UndoAmountEatenByOne(FoodGroupModel foodGroup)
        {
            if (foodGroup.AmountEaten != foodGroup.Quantity)
            {
                foodGroup.AmountEaten++;
                RefreashFoodGroupModel();
            }
        }
```

This workaround will cause the refresh of `ListView` items.

[image]

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 u r welcome. So have my reply answered your question?:) BTW, I'm not saying this is definitely Xamarin's bug, Xamarin team will investigate the root cause based on your bug report;)

Comment: I'm going to implement tonight, ill mark your answer when ready, sorry for delay and thanks again. It seems weird to have a bug that is obviously going to affect thousands of apps... Surely this is critical stuff that everyone is reporting.